# With clause, syntax error in recursive query

Tags: sql, mariadb, recursive-query

When running this query i get the error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WITH works as (SELECT ath.dblpkey from (authors as ath) where author in (sele...' at line 7

```
WITH RECURSIVE
authors as ((select dblpkey, author from inproau) union all (select dblpkey, author from artiau))
,collegues(collegue) as 
(
    SELECT "Paul Erdös" #as collegue
        UNION ALL
    (WITH works as (SELECT ath.dblpkey from (authors as ath) where author in (select collegue from collegues))
        (SELECT DISTINCT author from authors where dblpkey in (select dblpkey from works)))
) 
select * from collegues
```

I tried looking up the syntax rules of SQL but still I don't find what syntax rule I am breaking

Comment: You can't nest ctes.

Comment: You can't nest Withs. Insert WITH works as (SELECT ath.dblpkey from (author.... ) before the first With and it should work.

Comment: Seems like this query can be simplified a bit. Can you share a sample of your input table and corresponding expeceted output?

Answer (score 0):

As the commentors already said you can't nest CTEs, so works has to go up

You maybe could simplify it quite a bit but without data thisn will be impossible

```
WITH RECURSIVE
authors as (
            (select dblpkey, author from inproau) 
            union all 
            (select dblpkey, author from artiau))
,works as (SELECT ath.dblpkey from (authors as ath) where author in (select collegue from collegues)) 
,
collegues(collegue) as 
(
    SELECT "Paul Erdös" #as collegue
        UNION ALL    
        (SELECT DISTINCT author from authors where dblpkey in (select dblpkey from works))
) 
select * from collegues
```